# Pass C++ object to Java vs set object parameters one by one using JNI

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

I have searched for this question and found a few answers but have not really found what I am looking for.
I call Java using JNI from C++ and set a Java object's fields one by one. Something like below:

```
jobject jSomeObject = (jobject) JVM_ENV->CallObjectMethod(myObj, getObjMethodID, "");
JVM_ENV->CallVoidMethod(jSomeObject , setMethodID1, SomeIntVal);
JVM_ENV->CallVoidMethod(jSomeObject , setMethodID2, SomeStringVal);
```

All parameters inside the jSomeObject are set one by one like this. And you see that there are multiple JNI calls going on which is expensive. What I am thinking is, if there is a way that I set all the parameters in the native environment and send the object just once to avoid multiple JNI calls.
Some of the posts says that it is not possible to pass a custom object to JNI. Can I do it ?

Edit:
Above calls changed to something:

```
jobject jSomeObject = (jobject) JVM_ENV->CallObjectMethod(myObj, getObjMethodID, "");
someClass obj = new someClass();
obj.setMethod1(someInvVal);
obj.setMethod2(someStringVal); // so on...
JVM_ENV->CallVoidMethod(jSomeObject , setMethodID1, obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

No: You can only call methods and constructors and get and set fields that are defined in Java.

Yes: You can possibly define additional classes and methods in Java that will do what you need in one call. For example, `myObj:getObjMethodID` seems to be a factory method. You could add a method overload that takes all the values you want to initialize the created object with.

In general, if you can make things powerful in Java, the tasks done in JNI will be simpler.

Comment: myObj::getObjMethodID is factory but I can only set the parameters one by one and not at one go. I can't pass all the parameters in one go as there could be dozens of them. 
I have edited my post to show what I am looking for. Create an object on the native side and set that object to the Java side.